Vitest/React Testing Library - Error: Test timed out in 5000ms
In attempting to test setInterval() within the start_new_game() function nested within the <Simon /> component the following error is being raised:
Error: Test timed out in 5000ms. If this is a long-running test, pass a timeout 
value as the last argument or configure it globally with "testTimeout".

In searching how to resolve this I found a similar post here; the only difference being I'm using Vitest instead of Jest:

Fake timers doesn't work with latest version of user-event?

In implementing the answers provided there the aforementioned error is still being raised. To identify the problem lines I commented out lines one by one. The combination of the following is causing the problem:

vi.useFakeTimers() in conjunction with {advanceTimers: () => vi.runOnlyPendingTimers()
await user.click(power_button)

It's not clear to me why the test is timing out when all that is happening as shown here is invoking the turn_simon_on function which has nothing to do with a timing function like setInterval()?
import {test, expect, vi, beforeEach, afterEach} from "vitest";

import {render, screen, waitFor} from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

import {Simon, Pad} from "./components.jsx";

beforeEach(() => {
    vi.useFakeTimers();
});

afterEach(() => {
    vi.useRealTimers();
});

test(
    `
    Verify that clicking the start button (when the game is on) displays on the
    screen the beginning level (Level 1) (See function: start_new_game)
    `, async () => {
        const user = userEvent.setup({advanceTimers: () => vi.runOnlyPendingTimers()});
        render(<Simon />);
        const power_button = screen.getByRole("button", {name: "turn_game_on"})
        await user.click(power_button);
    }
);

function Simon(props) {
    
    const [level, setLevel] = useState("--");
    const [power, setPower] = useState(false);
    const [game, setGame] = useState(games[Math.floor(Math.random() * games.length)]);
    if (!isNaN(level)) {
        const round = game[parseInt(level)];
        const colors_remaining = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(round));
    }
    const [strictGame, setStrictGame] = useState(false);
    const timer = useRef(null);
    const time_limit = useRef(5);

    function turn_simon_on() {
        //Clicking the "power" button will enable the player to
        //start a new game and/or setting the game to strict mode
        setPower(!power);
    }

    function start_new_game() {
        //When "start" is clicked the game display will
        //blink "--" until the game is ready to play
        let i = 0;
        const indicators =  ["", "--", "", "0"];
        const interval_id = setInterval(
            () => {
                const indicator = indicators[i++];
                setLevel(indicator);
                if (indicator === "0") {
                    clearInterval(interval_id);
                }
            }, 500
        );
    }


<div className="start_button_wrapper">
    <button type="button" className="start_button" id="start_game" aria-label="start_new_game" onClick={start_new_game}></button>
    <p className="title">Start</p>
    </div>
        <div className="power_buttons_wrapper">
            <p className="title">Off</p>
            <button className={!power ? "power_button power_off" : "power_button power_on"} onClick={turn_simon_on} aria-label="turn_game_off"></button>
            <button className={power ? "power_button power_on" : "power_button power_off"} onClick={turn_simon_on} aria-label="turn_game_on"></button>


Turns out it is an issue with userEvents library, I solved it by using fireEvents instead.
https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/1115
